# Connecting a transparent proxy with a authenticated proxy

Tags: linux, proxy

At work, the networking department have an authenticated proxy(users have to use their LDAP login and password to connect to the internet).

On linux this means for me that I have to setup an http_proxy variable for each application(or one global, in .bashrc or .profile). The problem is that various applications use different methods or have varying degrees of support for proxy.

What I would really want is to route all http connections to the proxy with the headers set up with my credentials.

Is that possible? How?

---

Before you ask, yes it could have been easier if the networking team collaborated with me but they are not the most motivated group in the company so I'm alone on this one.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to set up a local proxy on your linux machine, and configure it with a parent proxy with authentication, but it's a bit of overkill, since you 'll have to handle HTTPS as well, thus you'll have to use sslBump technique. So on one hand you have applications that don't support proxy detection vie the environment variables, and on other hand - lot's of technical stuff.

I myself prefer the standard approach. I have exactly the same situation at my work.

Comment: Our proxy isn't using ssl bumping so why should I need to configure https?

Comment: HTTPS, transparent proxy and authentication don't live together. Since your goal is to mimic a generic client you'll with a transparent proxy, you'll need to set up an sslBump.